# SimpleJdbcCall executeObject() usage in Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I usually do this in my repository package:

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    procGetDeviceDetails = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withProcedureName("web_Device_Details")
        .returningResultSet("results", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Device.class));
}

public Device deviceDetails(Map input) {
    Map m = procGetDeviceDetails.execute(input);
    List<Device> list = (List<Device>) m.get("results");
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I wish to remove boilerplate in second method so I've switched to executeObject(). I tried this. Both failed.

```
public Device deviceDetails(Map input) {
    Device device = procGetDeviceDetails.executeObject(Device.class, input);
    return device;
}

public Device deviceDetails(Map input) {
    List<Device> device = procGetDeviceDetails.executeObject(List.class, input);
    return device.get(0);
}
```

Problem is that my device is null. I tried also declaring just Object instead of Device or List and it's still null. What am I doing wrong?

I know that result is correctly mapped into Device class because I see that procGetDeviceDetails (SimpleJdbcCall) has declaredRowParameters equal to {#result-set-1=org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper@79095fd7} and BeanPropertyRowMapper has mappedClass set to Device.

Seems that generics or something else troubles me. I found example here. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7270

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with stored procedure design. These methods in SimpleJdbcCall uses OUTPUT parameters while my stored procedures returns data normally as result set.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T executeObject(Class<T> returnType, Map<String, ?> args) {
    return (T) doExecute(args).get(getScalarOutParameterName());
}
```

Because of this I've created subclass of SimpleJdbcCall with two additional methods executeObjectSingle and executeObjectList which enables me simple usage.

```
public <T> T executeObjectSingle(Class<T> returnType, Map<String, ?> args) {
    List<T> o = executeObjectList(returnType, args);
    return o.get(0);
}

public <T> List<T> executeObjectList(Class<T> returnType, Map<String, ?> args) {
    Map<String, Object> m = doExecute(args);
    List<T> o = (List<T>) m.get(parameterNameResultSet);
    return o;
}
```

Of course this should be extended with size and null checking, but it shows the idea.

Stored procedure example in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Device_something]
    @device varchar(50),
    @username varchar(50),
    @password varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select 'foo' as token
    union
    select 'bar' as token
END
```